# Javascript regex matchAll : why rest operator is needed?

Tags: javascript, regex

In this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Why

```
const array = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
```

instead of just

```
const array = str.matchAll(regexp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.matchAll` returns an *iterator*. To create an array from the iterator, spreading the iterator into an array is one of the most concise ways to do it.

If you need an array, this is true for any iterator, not just `matchAll`.

But you don't necessarily need to create an array if you just need to iterate over an iterator. You can also use `for..of` to iterate without transforming into an array first, for example:

```
for (const match of str.matchAll(regexp)) {
  // do something with match
}
```

If you don't turn the iterator into an array first, and use the code in the linked example, logging the plain result won't be very informative:

```js
const regexp = /t(e)(st(\d?))/g;
const str = 'test1test2';

const iter = str.matchAll(regexp);
console.log(iter);
```

In the console, all you see is a `RegExpStringIterator` object without properties.

If you're wondering *why* `matchAll` returns an iterator instead of an array, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546456) - in short, it allows for performance optimizations in the (somewhat unusual) case that one might want to bail out of iterating over the string before retrieving all the possible matches.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **match** instead of **matchAll** it returns array :

```
let str = "abcd efgh";
let regex = /([a-z]+)/gi;
let arr = str.match(regex);

arr.forEach((el) => console.log(el));
```

output :

```
abcd
efgh
```

Comment: Thanks good answer also it's unfortunate I cannot mark both as good ones ;)